# logstash filter for metricbeat

Tags: logstash, metricbeat

I'm trying to rename a process metric data (metricbeat input) using logstash-filter-alter condrewrite option

```
filter {
  if [metricset][name] == "process" {
    alter {
      condrewrite => ["system.process.name", "php", "queue"]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not sure if the problem is with the if statement or the condrewrite statement. 
I'm using ELK stack 5.5.2

Comment: Have your tried `%{[system][process][name]}`?

Comment: @Imma I tried `condrewrite => ["%{[system][process][name]}", "php", "queue"]` but it doesn't help. without the quotes the logstash fail to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
filter {
  alter {
      condrewrite => ["[system][process][name]", "php", "queue"]
  }
}
```